# Subtracting pandas timestamps; absolute value

Tags: python, pandas

I have been playing a bit to try to understand pandas timestamps and timedeltas. I like how you can operate with them, but when trying subtraction I found this a bit odd:

```
now = pd.Timestamp('now')
then = now - pd.to_timedelta('1h')

print (now - then)
print (then - now)
print ((now - then).seconds)
print ((then - now).seconds)
```

Results in:

```
0 days 01:00:00
-1 days +23:00:00
3600
82800
```

a) How should I understand this behavior?

b) Is there a way to have an absolute value of the difference of timestamps, the equivalent to abs()?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason for this seemingly strange/buggy behaviour is that the `.seconds` attribute of a `timedelta` (for `pandas.Timedelta`, but this is inherited from standard library's `timedelta.timedelta`) is very ambigous.
The timedelta is stored in 3 parts: days, seconds, microseconds (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). So the `seconds` is the sum of hours, minutes and seconds (in seconds).

So there are 2 'strange' things that can lead to confusion:

- When having a negative timedelta, you get `-1 days +23:00:00` instead of `-01:00:00`. This is because only the `days` part can be negative. So a negative timedelta will always be defined as a negative number of days with adding hours or seconds again to get the correct value. So this gives you the `+23h` part.
- The seconds is the sum of hours, minutes and seconds. So the `+23:00:00` we get is equal to 82800 seconds.

Bottomline is, the `.seconds` attribute of a timedelta does not give you the seconds part neither the total seconds (timedelta converted to seconds). *So in practice, I think you should almost never use it.*

To obtain the timedelta in seconds, you can use the `total_seconds` method. If I define the negative difference to `diff = then - now`:

```
In [12]: diff
Out[12]: Timedelta('-1 days +23:00:00')

In [13]: diff.seconds
Out[13]: 82800

In [14]: diff.total_seconds()
Out[14]: -3600.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Although it is clear from your answer, I'll leave for clarity, to find the absolute value of a subtraction of timestamp: abs((ts1-ts2).total_seconds)